# Media data upload and performance

Tags: performance, api, rest, programming-languages

I need to create RESTful API for uploading media data. I need to be able to handle hundreds (thousands) of simultaneous requests. Once data is uploaded to my server, we are going to store it on Amazon S3 and populate some meta data into database. Could you advice in a few questions:

1) Which language is better for these kind of tasks ? (I'm familiar with PHP and Perl)

2) What about server? (nginx ?)

3) We need to be able to scale easily in case there are a lot of requests

4) Anything else you could point out and advice ?

Thank you

Comment: I would remove your personal comments about Perl and Java

Answer (score 0):

```
use feature ":5.16";
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);
use strict;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use Amazon::S3;

my $s3 = Amazon::S3->new
 ({aws_access_key_id     => "...",
   aws_secret_access_key => "...",
   retry                 => 1
  }
 );

my $b = $s3->bucket("Your bucket name");
my $f = "test.data"; 

$b->add_key_filename($f, "test.data", 
 {"x-amz-storage-class"=>"REDUCED_REDUNDANCY", 'x-amz-meta-version'=>'12.11.22', acl_short=>'public-read'
 });

say dump($b->errstr) if $b->errstr;
```